# What causes the "Windows was unable to communicate with target application" error when building out a Windows 8 app?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I'm building a Windows 8 app using Cordova in Visual Studio 2015. I'm using the Cordova project template that comes with VS 2015.

The app I'm building has been fine for all my debug builds, it has taken longer than usual at times, but I haven't had an issue yet.

I literally just updated some css and run the build and got a seemingly generic error "Windows was unable to communicate with target application"

After a waited for a moment I tried again and it worked. I'm also getting odd build errors. All this started doing very little changes, mainly with css (I am using grunt to compile my sass).

Two build errors I've seen say that my `www` folder was `not permitted` or that a a file called `Thumbs.db` could not be copied (however that file doesn't exist and never did in the folder the build references).

I've done Android development and I can run a cleanup to fix odd errors like this sometimes, not sure if I need to delete some files or run a command in VS. I've tried starting VS but the same issues pop up at, what seems, to be random times.

Comment: I feel like it might be as simple and deleting some generated files...?

Comment: I switched from `Windows-x86` to `Windows-x64` and it stopped erring (so far). However, it was working file for the past week and a half on `x86`